# Joomla Global Configuration allow access for administrator group

Tags: joomla, configuration, backend, access-rights

I need to allow the administrator group to access to System->Global Configuration page.
By Global Configuration page I intend that page that has the Site, System, Server, Permissions, Text and Filters tabs.

I don't see this component anywhere to configure it, so I understand that it is meant only for the Super Users.

So maybe I have to edit administrator/components/com_config. But where and how?

Comment: If you want to give them access to the Global Configuration, you may aswell make them a Super Admin

Answer (score 1):

The only way to give that kind of access is to make the users Super Admins under the Users section. You can see a list of the default user groups and their roles here: [Changing User Groups](http://docs.joomla.org/Changing_user_groups)
Here is the process to change a user's group:

1. Log into the Administrator Back-end via the sitename/administrator URL.
2. Click on Site, then User Manager
3. Click on the check box next to the user you want to change, then click Edit in the top right corner.
4. In the User Details section, change the user's group.
5. Click Save.